# Как добавить веб-сайт в Google Contacts с помощью API?

Tags: python, google-contacts

Я создаю контакт –

```
new_contact = gdata.contacts.data.ContactEntry()
new_contact.name = gdata.data.Name(full_name=gdata.data.FullName(text=Name))
new_contact.content = atom.data.Content(text=Notes)
new_contact.phone_number.append(gdata.data.PhoneNumber(text=num,
                                rel=gdata.data.WORK_REL, primary='true'))
new_contact.website.append(atom.data.Content(link1))
new_contact.website.append(atom.data.Content(link2'))
contact_entry = gd_client.CreateContact(new_contact)
```

Создается контакт с именем, заметками, телефоном, но без веб-сайтов. Как мне добавить веб-сайты в контакт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ios_href = gdata.contacts.data.Website(href=link1, label = 'iOS')
android_href = gdata.contacts.data.Website(href=link2, label = 'Android')
new_contact.website.extend([ios_href, android_href])
```